# How to change the marker size in pandas.scatter_matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

How to change the marker sizes in `pandas.scatter_matrix()` using python 3.5.2 and pandas 0.18.0?

Answer (score 5):

use the `s` parameter.

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2))
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.5, figsize=(8, 8), diagonal='kde', s=1000)
```

[image]